# Regex : How can I capture multiple text from this string?

Tags: python, regex

I have text from log file with format like this :

> {s:9:\\"batch_num\\";s:16:\\"4578123645712459\\";s:9:\\"full_name\\";s:8:\\"John
>   Doe\\";s:6:\\"mobile\\";s:12:\\"123456784512\\";s:7:\\"address\\";s:5:\\"Redacted"\\";s:11:\\"create_time\\";s:19:\\"2017-09-10
>   12:45:01\\";s:6:\\"gender\\";s:1:\\"1\\";s:9:\\"birthdate\\";s:10:\\"1996-03-09\\";s:11:\\"contact_num\\";s:1:\\"0\\";s:8:\\"identity\\";s:1:\\"2\\";s:6:\\"school\\";N;s:14:\\"school_city_id\\";N;s:17:\\"profile_pic\\";s:43:\\"profile\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg\\";s:14:\\"school_address\\";N;s:17:\\"enter_school_date\\";N;s:10:\\"speciality\\";}

Currently I can extract batch_num only with regex :

> (?<=batch_num\\\\";s:16:\\\\")([0-9]{1,16})(?=\\\)
>
> Link : https://regex101.com/r/OBaOY0/1/

**Question**

I want to extract value from batch_num, full_name and profile_pic.
My expected output is :

> 4578123645712459
>
> John Doe
>
> profile\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg

How do i get the desired output with the right regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the length of batch_num constant?                                                                          
And to get the profile_pic the pattern is "profileV[A-Za-z0-9]+".

Comment: Must it be done with a single regular expression?

Comment: Are all these backslashes really part of the string? Or are they artefact of a print?

Answer (score 3):

A solution to elegantly extract values by converting the string to json.

**Step 1**: Clean the string

```
import re, itertools
str_text = text.replace('\\','').replace(';','').replace('""','"').replace(':"','"').replace('N',',""')
str_text = re.sub('s:\d+',',', str_text)
str_text = re.sub('^{,','{', str_text)
str_text = re.sub('}$',':""}', str_text)
str_text = re.sub('(,)', lambda m, c=itertools.count(): m.group() if next(c) % 2 else ':', str_text)
str_text
#'{"batch_num":"4578123645712459","full_name":"John Doe","mobile":"123456784512","address":"Redacted","create_time":"2017-09-10 12:45:01","gender":"1","birthdate":"1996-03-09","contact_num":"0","identity":"2","school":"","school_city_id":"","profile_pic":"profile/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg","school_address":"","enter_school_date":"","speciality":""}'
```

**Step 2**: Convert string to json and extract

```
import json
str_json = json.loads(str_text)
print(str_json['batch_num'])
print(str_json['full_name'])
print(str_json['profile_pic'])
#4578123645712459
#John Doe
#profile/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg
```

Comment: Nice approach. Just one thing. Is it not advisable to avoid json as a variable name?

Answer (score 1):

With multiple regular expressions.

## Batch Number

`(?<="batch_num)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\d+)`

## Full Name

`(?<="full_name)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\w+\s\w+)`

## Full Name (with more than 2 words)

`(?<="full_name)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"([\w+\s]{1,})`

## Profile

`(?<="profile_pic)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\w+\\{2}\/\w+\.\w+)`

### Code

```
regex_batch = r'(?<="batch_num)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\d+)'
regex_name = r'(?<="full_name)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\w+\s\w+)'
regex_prof = r'(?<="profile_pic)\\{3}";s:\d+:\\{3}"(\w+\\{2}\/\w+\.\w+)'

test_str = "{s:9:\\\\\\\"batch_num\\\\\\\";s:16:\\\\\\\"4578123645712459\\\\\\\";s:9:\\\\\\\"full_name\\\\\\\";s:8:\\\\\\\"John Doe\\\\\\\";s:6:\\\\\\\"mobile\\\\\\\";s:12:\\\\\\\"123456784512\\\\\\\";s:7:\\\\\\\"address\\\\\\\";s:5:\\\\\\\"Redacted\"\\\\\\\";s:11:\\\\\\\"create_time\\\\\\\";s:19:\\\\\\\"2017-09-10 12:45:01\\\\\\\";s:6:\\\\\\\"gender\\\\\\\";s:1:\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\";s:9:\\\\\\\"birthdate\\\\\\\";s:10:\\\\\\\"1996-03-09\\\\\\\";s:11:\\\\\\\"contact_num\\\\\\\";s:1:\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\";s:8:\\\\\\\"identity\\\\\\\";s:1:\\\\\\\"2\\\\\\\";s:6:\\\\\\\"school\\\\\\\";N;s:14:\\\\\\\"school_city_id\\\\\\\";N;s:17:\\\\\\\"profile_pic\\\\\\\";s:43:\\\\\\\"profile\\\\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg\\\\\\\";s:14:\\\\\\\"school_address\\\\\\\";N;s:17:\\\\\\\"enter_school_date\\\\\\\";N;s:10:\\\\\\\"speciality\\\\\\\";}"

m_batch = re.findall(regex_batch, test_str, re.MULTILINE)[0]
m_name = re.findall(regex_name, test_str, re.MULTILINE)[0]
m_prof = re.findall(regex_prof, test_str, re.MULTILINE)[0]
print(m_batch, m_name, m_prof)
```

### Output

`4578123645712459 John Doe profile\\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg`

Comment: what if full name have middle name and last name ? Ex: Patty Marsh Holt. I want to cover both, beacause  in some case, the name value have First name only or full name

Comment: With this you can match any kind of names. `https://regex101.com/r/OBaOY0/3`

Answer (score 0):

I think i have one for you. The jpeg match group2 excludes the two //'s which is why they are in pink, they are the same match group:

https://regex101.com/r/OBaOY0/2

```
import itertools, re
a = '{s:9:\\"batch_num\\";s:16:\\"4578123645712459\\";s:9:\\"full_name\\";s:8:\\"John Doe\\";s:6:\\"mobile\\";s:12:\\"123456784512\\";s:7:\\"address\\";s:5:\\"Redacted"\\";s:11:\\"create_time\\";s:19:\\"2017-09-10 12:45:01\\";s:6:\\"gender\\";s:1:\\"1\\";s:9:\\"birthdate\\";s:10:\\"1996-03-09\\";s:11:\\"contact_num\\";s:1:\\"0\\";s:8:\\"identity\\";s:1:\\"2\\";s:6:\\"school\\";N;s:14:\\"school_city_id\\";N;s:17:\\"profile_pic\\";s:43:\\"profile\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg\\";s:14:\\"school_address\\";N;s:17:\\"enter_school_date\\";N;s:10:\\"speciality\\";}'.replace("\\","")

list(filter(None, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall(r'(?:s:16:\")(\d+)|(?:s:8:\")(\w+ \w+)|(?:s:43:\")(\w+/\w+\.\w+)', a)))))
```

output:

```
['4578123645712459',
 'John Doe',
 'profile/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all 3 matches for the example data using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a capturing group:

```
\b(?:batch_num|full_name|profile_pic)\b\\\\\\";s:\d+:\\\\\\"([^"]+)\\\\\\"
```

In parts

- `\b(?:batch_num|full_name|profile_pic)\b` Match one of the options between word boundaries
- `\\\\\\";s:\d+:` Match `\\\"s:` and 1+ digits
- `\\\\\\"` Match `\\\"`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^"]+` Match 1+ times char except `"`
- `)` Close group
- `\\\\\\"` Match `\\\"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/neCOeV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Mr4RBG)

For example

```
import re

regex = r'\b(?:batch_num|full_name|profile_pic)\b\\\\\\";s:\d+:\\\\\\"([^"]+)\\\\\\"'
test_str = r'''{s:9:\\\"batch_num\\\";s:16:\\\"4578123645712459\\\";s:9:\\\"full_name\\\";s:8:\\\"John Doe\\\";s:6:\\\"mobile\\\";s:12:\\\"123456784512\\\";s:7:\\\"address\\\";s:5:\\\"Redacted"\\\";s:11:\\\"create_time\\\";s:19:\\\"2017-09-10 12:45:01\\\";s:6:\\\"gender\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:9:\\\"birthdate\\\";s:10:\\\"1996-03-09\\\";s:11:\\\"contact_num\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:8:\\\"identity\\\";s:1:\\\"2\\\";s:6:\\\"school\\\";N;s:14:\\\"school_city_id\\\";N;s:17:\\\"profile_pic\\\";s:43:\\\"profile\\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg\\\";s:14:\\\"school_address\\\";N;s:17:\\\"enter_school_date\\\";N;s:10:\\\"speciality\\\";}'''
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['4578123645712459', 'John Doe', 'profile\\\\/2df0d9f29ab3ha65fed4847c8lb1o9sa.jpeg']
```